# Set value of variable to a classname

Tags: c#

I've two inherited classes. These classes have some static variables. What I want to do is that I want to set value of an object to its child class name and call child class methods with parent object. Here's the sample code:

```
class BlueSwitch : Switch {
    public static string Foo = "bar";
}

class Green : Switch {
    public static string Foo = "bar2";
}

Switch oSwitch = BlueSwitch;
Console.WriteLine(oSwitch.Foo); // should print out "bar" but instead i get compiler error
oSwitch = GreenSwitch;
Console.WriteLine(oSwitch.Foo); // should print out "bar2" but instead i get compiler error
```

Any other ideas how can I do this?

Comment: `Switch oSwitch = BlueSwitch;` won't even compile. You have to create an instance like `Switch oSwitch = new BlueSwitch();`

Comment: To call via instance of your classes you'd have to `new` an instance and then in those classes perhaps define a readonly instance property that returns the static value. But why not just call it via the static `BlueSwitch.Foo`? Also a bad idea to expose a static field like that since it's not readonly and could be changed by anyone

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here is, very not logical. You are asigning to the variable **oSwitch** a class name. That's not possible.

What you should do is :

```
Switch oSwitch = new BlueSwitch();
// this will print bar
oSwitch = new GreenSwitch();
// this will print bar2
```

> Side note

Your fields are static, and your variable **oSwitch** is a **Switch** Type. If you want to do things right, either make your class fields to public fields (which is also bad) and remove the static thing which will give you this :

```
class BlueSwitch : Switch {
    public string Foo = "bar";
}

class Green : Switch {
    public string Foo = "bar2";
}
```

Or you can let them stay static, but your code will become

```
string test = BlueSwitch.Foo;
// writes bar
test = GreenSwitch.Foo;
// writes bar2
```